# SSRS Only repeat some header rows

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, visual-studio-2013, ssrs-tablix

I have a report in SSRS that starts with three header rows and then has a total row.  I want the three header rows to repeat on each page, but not the total row.

For the three header rows, I have their property settings at:

> KeepWithGroup - After
>
> RepeatOnNewPage - True

and the total row at:

> KeepWithGroup - None
>
> RepeatOnNewPage - False

When trying to preview the report, I get the following error message:

> The tablix 'table1' has an invalid TablixMember. The TablixMember must
>   have the same value set for the RepeatOnNewPage property as those
>   following or preceding the dynamic TablixMember. (Expected Value:
>   "True"; Actual Value: "False")

I've experimented with other settings, but I can't seem to get this to work.  I have a group and detail set immediately following the total row, which is listed as static in the Row Groups listing.  I also have the same total row at the end of the report.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm very interested in the answer here as well.  I tried many settings and have been unable to find an answer as help.  Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that if it is created using a Matrix rather than a Table, you can add a Total Row to your outer group, then use the option "Repeat header columns on each page" in Tablix properties.

[**See here**](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/bce8e4ce-3b42-4fe0-aa91-0e8abf28b9d7/ssrs-2008-r2-repeat-headers-for-some-static-elements-but-not-all?forum=sqlreportingservices)

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a hacky way to deal with it, but I found a solution that worked for me.

I added a hardcoded column to my dataset, and added that value (now present on every row) as the parent group.  This allowed me to list global totals at the top of the report without interfering with how SSRS wanted to display the tablix header.

Again - I'm sure this is a contravention of how SSRS is supposed to operate, but it worked perfectly for me in my situation.

Answer (score 0):

My workaround, I have added both the headers ( you can add on the bases of requirement) in first row and then set below properties.

```
KeepTogether= True, 
KeepWithGroup=After,
RepeatOnNewPage= TRUE
```

***Before:***

[image]

***After:***

[image]